# How to pass form field value to java function on submit of form?

Tags: javascript

Here is my form:

```
    <form  id="aform">
    <input type="text" id="rollno" name="rollno">
    <input type="button" value="show result" onclick="showResultFunction ('someurl.com','divtodisplayresult');>
    </form>
```

**Question:**
Can I pass rollno entered in the function onclick as parameter? Like:

```
    onclick="showResultFunction ('someurl.com','divtodisplayresult',rollno);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript get input text value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/javascript-get-input-text-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to do:

```
onclick="showResultFunction ('someurl.com','divtodisplayresult', document.getElementById('rollno').value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, in the Javascript function itself, you can access the rollno value in code:

```
function showResultFunction(url, div)
{
    var rollno = document.getElementById("rollno");
    alert(rollno.value);
}
```